# How to show a custom message box at last point, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip says

> The tooltip appears when hovering **over** a point in a series.

But what if I need a custom tooltip to show at the last point even though not hover on the point to demonstrate some loading information like this:

[image: demo]

Comment: Tooltip is designed to display on hover. You can imitate method by calling `chart.tooltip.refresh(point)`, where `point` comes from `chart.series[index].data[another_index]`. Or you can use `chart.renderer` to render label there. It depends if you want to have sticky label over last point, or just show this tooltip on init.

Comment: @PawełFus , thank you ! I need a sticky one and it should be able to remove or show problematically . Just like this demo, no matter how to implement. Would you please give me a quick fiddle?

Comment: I don't have such fiddle to give you. I can suggest you to use [this plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/28/Current%20Price%20Indicator). Or you will need to write this on your own. Including hide/show that label. Or maybe consider enabling dataLabel for the last point? Then simply call `point.update()` to hide/show label?

Comment: @PawełFus , 1. The plugin is for Highstock, can I use for highcharts? 2. How can I control the datalabel only for the last point (use a formatter and determine if it is the last point or just return undefined?), and how to hide/show it pragmatically?

Comment: 1) Try it ;) 2) Like this: `data: [ 10, 20, 30, { y: 50, dataLabels: { enabled: true } }]`. 3) To hide call `point.update({ dataLabels: { enabled: false } });`.

Comment: And simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1vpq4cu6/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag on serie, which should have a label. Then in [load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load) event get last point from serie and print label by [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer).

```
load: function () {
                var chart = this,
                    series = this.series,
                    len, lastPoint;

                $.each(series, function (i, s) {
                    if (s.options.showLabel) {
                        len = s.data.length - 1;
                        lastPoint = s.data[len];

                        chart.renderer.text('Label', lastPoint.plotX + chart.plotLeft, lastPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop)
                            .css({
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        })
                            .add();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nf7ne/55/

Comment: I found `label` method will more powerful and can give me div supported, but I need one more thing. the control to hide it or show it pragmatically . can I do that?

Comment: Labels has no reference in chart, so you cannot show/hide that dynamically. Better is using renderer as I suggest.

Comment: I mean http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.label , which is under renderer, can't I dynamically show/hide it?

Comment: I thought that you mean labels build-in chart cofniguration not renderer. Anyway with renderer you can show/hide. Keep renderered object for example in variable, then call show/hide method.